# Read STDIN in child process after exiting parent process

Tags: c, stdin, child-process

I'm looking for a way to read  from STDIN(console) in child process, after closing parent process.

My program should be like:
parent process forks and creates child process.
After creating child process, parent MUST be closed. I can not use functions such as `wait()` etc.

The thing is, when I exit from parent process, I can not read from console anymore. Is there any way to 'pass the control' to child process, instead of passing it back to shell ?

Instructions:

Process 1: reads data (sigle lines) from standard input stream and passes it with ipc message queue to process 2.

Process 2: receives data send by process 1 and prints it in standard output stream.

Two processes should be executed automatically from 1 initiative process. After executing child processes, initiative process should immediatelly close.

Comment: You want your child process to read from stdin of the shell where parent process was executed? You can replace process with another via `exec`, but what do you intend to do with multiple processes?

Comment: Let me guess: STDIN is the console?

Comment: Yes, exactly - I want to read from stdin where parent process was executed.  It is a part of a school assignment. I must have: one main process which role is only to run two child processes and then immediately close.  First child process have to read from stdin of the shell, and send whatever it reads to second child process using IPC message queue. Second process just prints received message to stdout.

Comment: Unless `stdin` is close-on-exec, the child should be able to read from it after the parent is terminated. What you are experiencing, however, is probably a conflict with the terminal's process group control and the shell's job control. When the parent dies, the shell takes back over as the foreground process of the terminal. Background processes trying to read from the terminal get a `SIGTTIN`.  Is it explicitly requested to read from the terminal from the *child process*, because that seems simply a bad idea (why not keep the parent)?

Comment: I'm using fgets() in my child process and it doesn't wait for user to type something. The message is empty. And yes, it is requested to read from the terminal in child process.

Comment: I have added an instrunction I have received from teacher. Maybe I just misunderstood something.

Comment: Try running your process with piped-in input, like `cat inputfile | initiator` . Is the result any different?

Comment: It works fine, but the program is supposed to get message many times. With `cat inputfile | initiator`, it's executed just once and then it quits.

Comment: Find out if stdin has FD_CLOEXEC set (use `fcntl(0, F_GETFD)` ). If it's set, try unsetting it.

Comment: It's not set. I think that the problem is what @dhke said in previous comment. But how to bring child process back to foreground after closing parent?